# Basic dojo 1.7 simple web application with an elegant infrastructure (e.g dojo boilerplate)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo

I have come accross an [sample application with dojo 1.5](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-dojotoolkit/section2.html), but it's not really what I want to achieve : it is not modular at all. I want to make use of the amd, and various design patterns (like MVC) to have a very organize application. Unfortunately, the dojo community and "example" are not quite visible or present (compare to Jquery). There's a lot of cool tutorials on various implementation of specific dojo features, but none that's explain the very basic on how to create a simple (but at the same time, complex) squeleton for a dojo project. I came across the [dojo boilerplate project on github](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate), and tried to start from there, but I find it really hard (as a beginner) to implement such trivial things such as an login or basic interface (and separate all that by module, event handling, data, etc.).  I just don't want to make a dojo application by using only an index.html and one javascript file, I could do it, but for maintenance and adding stuff, it will just be a complete mess. With this post, I hope to gain some information on this specific subject and perhaps create a tutorial for dojo on how to start up a real web application. For example, applying the mvc pattern, I think a good application tutorial should have a login example (authentification) and a basic modular interface (like some kind of main container, and on various events, the container ui change for instance with different widget). I'll be working on something on github and posting up when I'm done. If your done before go ahead ;)

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [**TodoMVC**](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) at [GitHub](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc):

> a project which offers the same Todo application implemented using MV*
>   concepts in most of the popular JavaScript MV* frameworks of today.

It employs `dojox.mvc` @PEM mentioned. It's not a typical way of building Dojo applications as `dojox.mvc` was released just on May 16th, 2011, but it is worth looking at. There is also [live demo](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/dojo/index.html) and tutorial **Creating Todo MVC in Dojo**:

- [Overview](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2012/01/28/dojomvc_overview/)
- [Part 1: Models](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2012/02/26/dojomvc-models/)
- [Part 2: Views](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2012/04/13/dojomvc-views/)
- [Part 3: Controllers](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2012/05/26/dojomvc-controllers/)

Also have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/dojo/dwb) of [Dojo Web Builder](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/) (+ article [Introducing the New Dojo Web Builder](http://dojotoolkit.org/blog/introducing-the-new-dojo-web-builder)).

Last but not least is [Maqetta](http://maqetta.org/) ([sources at GitHub](https://github.com/maqetta/maqetta)), the most complex Dojo application one can find. Look esp. in `maqetta.core.client/WebContent/` directory.

Comment: I didn't come accross that TodoMVC for some reason, but I will definitely have a look at it. I found this one, which seem pretty cool also https://github.com/rmurphey/dojo-demo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not searched enough?
Dojo MVC :

- http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mvc
- http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/data_modeling/

> I just don't want to make a dojo application by using only an index.html and one javascript file

But that's basically what Dojo is for and good at...
If you just want to make cute animation on a plain old html website, rather go for jquery, it's sexier.

Now if you want to do a "real web application" then dojo is the right framework. But you'll also have to learn how to use it.

Comment: I came accross those tutorial, actually I have read all the tutorials. The things is more of putting all that stuff togheter in an elegant way. Maybe, I'm reading it all wrong. It's just where I go from there. I take for example GWT, they give you a squeletton application of the bat, then it's a matter of "tweaking" and implementing your stuff (with design pattern for example). So, it's more like, how do you create a maintanable and organize dojo project... That's why I choosen Dojo over jquery, it's just hard for a new comer to start (with that mentality in mind), but with no clear example.

Comment: I understand your point. I know it will not help but I came to realize that having to do it from scratch helps you understand faster and better how things works rather than having a pre-made squeletton to tweak and hack. Though, you are right, it takes longer and the learning curve is steeper. I'd recommand freenode #dojo chan on irc. Lot's of people to help you there.

Comment: I mean you are right too. It's important to know what you are doing. It's just more fun when you are starting to code and see a direct progression. Thank you. I'll come by for sure on irc ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with building a sample application tutorial.

First, a sample application with what you have described will need a web server to communicate with. Dojo is web server agnostic,  so what technology do you choose to for the sample application?  Secondly, a server is now required to make the demo available online, or the person interested in looking at the demo would need to install the web server. As simple as this sounds, it is a barrier and prevents a more novice person from continuing.

Second, even with a web server there are many ways to build/architect a web application.

> I think a good application tutorial should have a login example
>   (authentification) and a basic modular interface (like some kind of
>   main container, and on various events, the container ui change for
>   instance with different widget)

From what you have posted, it reads like you are looking for a single page application.  There are downsides to single page apps (such as SEO) and creating a sample single page application needs to make it clear to the developer what the downsides of using the sample are.  It's not the magic bullet for all Dojo/Web applications.

I have a project up on Github and it certainly isn't ready for primetime, but you can take a look.  This is a Single Page Application that uses Java/Spring for the backend server.  I am a couple days away from checking in the Spring Pet Clinic example which will demonstrate some of the functionality.  I also need to update the wiki to describe how to create a sample application.

https://github.com/cswing/evinceframework

Also, I use the theme tester often to take a look at different widgets.  Not entirely what you are looking for, but some who get to this question may find the link useful.

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html

Comment: You are completely right, but a simple example with json data for example could be done (artificial data) should solve partially the server part (because I don't really care about the server part, since I understand quite well depending on which language I'm using). And yes, you are quite right, I'm looking for a single page application. Thank you for your response. I'll have a look at your project.